# Is the following an example of closure?

Tags: javascript

I have a function here that flattens nested arrays. I see that it uses recursion to call itself to get to the bottom of nested arrays. However, after every time it calls itself, the variable `ret` is reset to an empty array.

How is this function is able to remember the past values it used to have in `ret`? Is this an example of closure?

```
function steamrollArray(ary) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if(Array.isArray(ary[i])) {
            ret = ret.concat(steamrollArray(ary[i]));
        } else {
            ret.push(ary[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Comment: No! There is no closures here!

Comment: No, this isn't a closure. It's just an example of variable scope. Every call to a function has its own set of local variables.

Comment: Local variables are kept in a stack. Each call to the function has its own stack frame that contains its variable bindings.

Comment: @Barmar In that case, are there multple stack frames here with each having a ret with different value. But how do they combine at the end?

Comment: @stepbystep this is a recursive function and you are concatenating the results in each call

Comment: @stepbystep `ret = ret.concat(steamrollArray(ary[i]));` combines the current value of `ret` with the value returned by the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a recursive function, but is it not a *closure*. A closure has to do with nested functions being "closing over" (by the curly braces of another function) and how the inner function has access to the parent scopes local variables.

For example, this is an example of a closure in JavaScript:

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

add();
add();
add();

// the counter is now 3
```

Notice that when add(); is called the inner function is being run, but it still has access to the *counter* variable in the parent scope.